# Typescript Omit<> does not show error when spreading object with omitted attribute

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects

Why can't TypeScript see that i am trying to spread object of type Human which have attribute that is not in type Baby ? This works not only for this example, it works for **any** object the is super set of attributes. For TS to not show an error is enough to have all attributes of the type but you can pass more than you need. Why? What is the point of type if i can pass any superset object to it..

Do i really have to manualy pick attributes from the upper object to be sure that i don't pass more than i need.
Imagine if i omit 100 attributes and spread the object and still get all that attributes in memory. That defeat the purpose of my type

```
interface Human {
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  age: number;
}
const human1: Human = {
  name: "Chad",
  surname: "Lingovski",
  age: 26,
};
type Baby = Omit<Human, "age">;
const baby1: Baby = { ...human1 }; //this is allowed, why?
const baby2: Baby = { name: "Chad", surname: "Lingovski", age: 26 }; //this is not allowed
```

I expect TS to show error. It does not let me access age attribute, but i can console.log the whole object and age is there.

Comment: Because typescript only stops you from adding literal keys that aren't present. `Baby` is still assignable to `Human`.

Comment: Because `Human` has every property that `Baby` needs

Comment: My question is why i can asign Human to Baby if i said explicitly what my type need. I dont need more, i need exactly what i wrote

Comment: TypeScript doesn't have "exact" types (see feature request at [ms/TS#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)).  Every `Human` is also a `Baby`; that's how structural typing works.  The error you want would also stop someone from assigning subtypes to types.  TS only produces excess property warnings in situations where the compiler would completely forget the extra property, which doesn't happen when spreading an existing value that knows about it.

Comment: See the linked q/a for the reasons why this doesn't cause an error; if you want to omit properties at runtime you'll have to do it in JS code, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpjQzw) maybe.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks. By now i understood that i have to do it manually....what a bummer